# laravel/passport tables already exist

Tags: laravel-5, laravel-passport

I am using laravel/passport for oauth login, however tables needed for passport already exist to my Database.

To create new table I have to edit vendor folder and I don't want to go with this approach.

Any help to override passport migration class to create new tables with my specific name.

Thanks in advance.